# Compare two arrays save data to matches

Tags: php

I have two arrays I need to compare....

$Drink Array

```
(
[0] => Drink Object
    (
        [top_id] => 40C6-88
        [name] => Pepsi
        [drink_id] => E936
    )

[1] => Drink Object
    (
        [top_id] => 46DB-9E
        [name] => Orange Juice
        [drink_id] => E936
    )
)

[2] => Drink Object
    (
        [top_id] => 5J71-4F79
        [name] => Dr Pepper     
        [drink_id] => E936
    )
```

$DrinkItem Array

```
(
[0] => DrinkItem Object
    (
        [bottom_id] => 45BD-92DD
        [name] => Diet Coke      
        [drink_template_id] => 3B2A-4D82
    )

[1] => DrinkItem Object
    (
        [bottom_id] => 4A71-8F79
        [name] => Orange Juice     
        [drink_template_id] => 3B2A-4D82
    )


)
```

.. If the name matches one of the names in the DrinkItem Array I need to store the top_id of that item.

I was trying to do something like:

```
foreach ($Drink as $d) {
    foreach ($DrinkItem as $item){
        if ($d->name == $item->name){
            $match = $d->top_id;
        }
    }
}
```

But I might be way off base here. If there's a better approach for storing the id of the matches, or if i'm on the right track, any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Since there are objects inside the array, the loops is the only solution that comes to my mind. You may want to remove the matches from the arrays to shorten the loops.

Comment: Do you need to find all `top_id`s which match the criterion?

Comment: You're on the right track, but this isn't the most *efficient* solution. It will execute in [O(n^2) time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). If efficiency is important then let me know and I may be able to give you a better solution. Otherwise, there's something to be said for keeping it simple to understand.

Note: My alternative solutions would probably deal with hashing. Dragging down memory efficiency in favor of time efficiency.

Comment: Yep, I need to find every top_id of which the name is a match

Comment: ShaneC, tough call. At this point, happy to have it working. If the optimal solution isn't that much more work, I would hate to ignore a better solution. But no problem either way, thanks for the comment :).

Comment: @mstef General advice: 1. Do the simplest thing that could possibly work. 2. Fix it only if it needs fixing. You definitely have the simplest solution. And I suspect that the performance of the whole application is just fine.

Comment: good advice, holds true a lot of the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off creating an index first:

```
$drinkindex = array();

// Note that names need to be unique.
foreach ($Drink as $d) {
    $drinkindex[$d->name] = $d->top_id;
}

$matches = array();
foreach ($DrinkItem as $di) {
    $match = $drinkindex[$di->name];
    if ($match!==NULL) {
        $matches[$match] = True;
    }
}

// $matches is a set of top_id.
// If you may have duplicates and you want those represented, use a list instead.
```

If you need the entire `Drink` object and not just the `top_id`, consider using array intersection, like so:

```
function namecompare($a, $b) {
    if ($a->name === $b->name) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return ($a->name < $b->name) ? -1: 1;
    }
}

$intersection = array_uintersect($Drink, $Drinkitem, 'namecompare');

var_dump($intersection); // contains $Drink[1];
```

Comment: Francis Avila = my hero. Thanks a ton man, way above and beyond. Extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is obviously `O(n*m)`.

<sub>`n` and `m` denote the lengths of the arrays `$Drink` and `$DrinkItem`.</sub>

You can solve the problem in O(n+m) time, assuming you have access to a hash-based map with amortized `O(1)` insert/fetch performance.

1. Initialize an empty map and an empty list.
2. Iterate through `$Drink` array and store each object in the map, using its `name` as the key.
3. Iterate through `$DrinkItem` and for each `$drink_item`, check if `$drink_item->name` maps to a `Drink` object in the map.

   - If it does, add the mapped `Drink` object's `top_id` to the list.

The list contains the `top_id`s, and you've got them in `O(n+m)` time.

Edit: Francis Avila's post contains actual PHP code that does exactly this.

Comment: thank you Irfy! (actually extremely helpful seeing this run-down and then seeing it in action)